# Easier way to write this code? Maybe using a loop?

Tags: r

I have this code here:

```
test = test %>% left_join(dischargestatuscode, by = "DischargeStatusID") %>% select(-DischargeStatusID) %>% select(-Code)
test = test %>% left_join(statecode, by = "StateID") %>% select(-StateID) %>% select(-Code)
test = test %>% left_join(gendercode, by = "GenderID") %>% select(-GenderID) %>% select(-Code) %>% select(-Gender.1ID)
test = test %>% left_join(racecode, by = "RaceID") %>% select(-RaceID) %>% select(-Code)
test = test %>% left_join(agecode, by = "AgeID") %>% select(-AgeID) %>% select(-Code) %>% select(-(MinAge:MaxAge))
test = test %>% left_join(icd9codes, by = "ICDAccessCodeID") %>% select(-ICDAccessCodeID) %>% select(-(ICD9Code:CodeType)) 
       %>% select(-LongDescription)
test = test %>% left_join(diagnosistypecode, by = "DiagnosisCodeTypeID") %>% select(-DiagnosisCodeTypeID) %>% select(-Code)
test = test %>% left_join(hcpcscode, by = "HCPCCodeID") %>% select(-HCPCCodeID) %>% select(-Code)
test = test %>% left_join(countycode, by = "CountyID") %>% select(-CountyID) %>% select(-Code)
```

I was just wondering if there was an easier way to write this.  I was thinking maybe a for loop or maybe an lapply?  Thank you very much for the help!

Code that i thought of that may work:

```
for (i in seq(CodeList)) {
  test %>% left_join(i, by = i[1])
}
```

Comment: You have different datasets with different grouping columns, select columns etc.  May be you create a list with dataset objects, a vector of same length of grouping columns and select columns, and then use `lapply` or for loop

Comment: It helps too to describe what you're trying to achieve in plain language.

Comment: I am trying to possibly condense this code.  I am looking to make it shorter because the begining parts are all the same, and the ID variables are all the first column of the code description tables.

Comment: the select statements at the end can be addressed later though, thanks!

Comment: i attached some code that i believe may be pointing in the right direction to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As there is always a `left_join` with data and by argument, followed by a select with one argument, these actions can be wrapped in a function. Only thing that needs caution is argument evaluation. This was handled by `quote` and `eval` and should work fine with other inputs.

Note: This will only make your code shorter horizontally

```
> set.seed(4)   # toy data generation
> dat <- data.frame(id = 1:4, char = letters[sample(1:4)])
> dat2 <- data.frame(id = 1:4, char = letters[sample(1:4)])

> library(dplyr)
> f <- function(y1, by1, s2)
  dat %>% left_join(y1, by = by1) %>% select(eval(s2))

# example usage
> f(dat2, 'id', quote(-id))
  char.x char.y
1      c      d
2      a      a
3      d      b
4      b      c

> f(dat2, 'id', quote(id:char.x))
  id char.x
1  1      c
2  2      a
3  3      d
4  4      b
```

These can be extended easily to two select operations and third being optional.

Comment: i will be trying this soon.  This looks like this is in the right direction.  I just need to wait for the server to get back on.